# Mapping device tree interrupt flags to devm_request_irq

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am currently writing a device driver for Linux for use of PowerPC.

The device tree entry is as follows:

```c
// PPS Interrupt client 
pps_hwirq {
    compatible = "pps-hwirq";
    interrupts = <17 0x02>;                     // IPIC 17 = IRQ1, 0x02 = falling edge
    interrupt-parent = < &ipic >;
};
```

The 0x02 flag is quite important - the [PPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-per-second_signal) is aligned with the falling edge, but this is not universal on GPS receivers and therefore should be configurable.

In the `probe()` function of the driver, obtaining the IRQ number is straightforward:

```c
hwirq = irq_of_parse_and_map(np, 0);
if (hwirq == NO_IRQ) {
    dev_err(&pdev->dev, "No interrupt found in the device tree\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

But how does one map the the IRQ flags from the device tree to the driver?

```c
/* ****TODO****: Get the interrupt flags from the device tree 
 * For now, hard code to suit my problem, but since this differs
 * by GPS receiver, it should be configurable.
 */
flags = IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING;

/* register IRQ interrupt handler */
ret = devm_request_irq(&pdev->dev, data->irq, pps_hwint_irq_handler,
                       flags, data->info.name, data);
```

Unfortunately, there are few - if any - examples in the tree that actually do this job - most leave this flag as 0 (leave as-is) - here's a snippet of the results when `grep` for `devm_request_irq`, noting the values for the flags:

```
./drivers/crypto/mxs-dcp.c:     ret = devm_request_irq(dev, dcp_vmi_irq, mxs_dcp_irq, 0,
./drivers/crypto/mxs-dcp.c:     ret = devm_request_irq(dev, dcp_irq, mxs_dcp_irq, 0,
./drivers/crypto/omap-sham.c:   err = devm_request_irq(dev, dd->irq, dd->pdata->intr_hdlr,
./drivers/crypto/omap-aes.c:            err = devm_request_irq(dev, irq, omap_aes_irq, 0,
./drivers/crypto/picoxcell_crypto.c:    if (devm_request_irq(&pdev->dev, irq->start, spacc_spacc_irq, 0,
```

Or hard code it to what the hardware actually asserts:

```
./drivers/crypto/tegra-aes.c:   err = devm_request_irq(dev, dd->irq, aes_irq, IRQF_TRIGGER_HIGH |
```

So how does one cleanly associate this property from the device tree to the actual driver?

Comment: What is the type of driver you're trying to write? In other words, what is the function you are using to register your driver?

Comment: The actual type of driver is irrelevant to the question - I have it working with the flags hard-coded to IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, which is what essentially very other driver does (or sets it to zero for no change).

What I want to do is full this value from the device tree and give it devm_request_irq.

Answer (score 10):

Further I'm gonna show how to obtain IRQ number and IRQ flags from Device Tree in some common cases:

- in I2C drivers
- in platform drivers
- manually

### In I2C drivers

#### In short

If you're writing an I2C driver, you don't need to read IRQ parameters from DT manually. You can rely on I2C core to populate IRQ parameters for you:

- in your `probe()` function, `client->irq` will contain the IRQ number
- `devm_request_irq()` will use IRQ flags from DT automatically (just don't pass any IRQ trigger flags to that function).

#### Details

Let's look at the [i2c_device_probe()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L806) function (it's where your driver's `probe()` function is being called from):

```c
static int i2c_device_probe(struct device *dev)
{
    ...
    if (dev->of_node) {
        ...
        irq = of_irq_get(dev->of_node, 0);
    }
    ...
    client->irq = irq;
    ...
    status = driver->probe(client, i2c_match_id(driver->id_table, client));
}
```

So, `client->irq` will already contain IRQ number in your driver's probe function.

As for IRQ flags: `of_irq_get()` (in code above) eventually calls `irqd_set_trigger_type()`, which internally stores IRQ flags (read from device tree) for your interrupt number. So, when you call `devm_request_irq()`, it eventually ends up in `__setup_irq()`, and it does next:

```c
/*
 * If the trigger type is not specified by the caller,
 * then use the default for this interrupt.
 */
if (!(new->flags & IRQF_TRIGGER_MASK))
    new->flags |= irqd_get_trigger_type(&desc->irq_data);
```

where:

- `new->flags` contains flags you provided to `devm_request_irq()`
- `irqd_get_trigger_type()` returns flags obtained from DT

In other words, if you don't pass IRQ flags to `devm_request_irq()` (e.g. pass 0), it will use IRQ flags obtained from device tree.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36477695/3866447) for details.

### In platform drivers

You can use `platform_get_irq()` to obtain IRQ number. It also stores (internally) IRQ flags obtained from DT, so if you pass `flags=0` to `devm_request_irq()`, flags from DT will be used.

### Manually

If your driver doesn't rely on kernel frameworks, you have to obtain IRQ values manually:

- IRQ number can be obtained (as you mentioned) by `irq_of_parse_and_map()`; this function not only returns IRQ number, but also stores IRQ flags for your IRQ number (by calling `irqd_set_trigger_type()` eventually); stored IRQ flags will be automatically used in `devm_request_irq()`, if you don't pass IRQ trigger type to it (e.g. you can pass `flags=0`)
- IRQ flags can be obtained by [irq_get_trigger_type()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1f6236bfd7c38d5f9f7648fae7215e65274b9e63), but only after executing `irq_of_parse_and_map()`

  So probably you only need to run `irq_of_parse_and_map()` and let `devm_request_irq()` handle flags for you (just make sure you don't pass trigger flags to it).

Comment: do you know why if I use request_irq() or devm_request_irq() for an SPI device (for which spi_drv_probe does almost the same as i2c_device_probe does), then after unloading the module and of course doing free_irq or even explicitly calling devm_free_irq, and then trying to load the same module again, I get an "irq: type mismatch, failed to map hwirq..." message?

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin My guess is some other device clashes with that IRQ (maybe some bug in some driver), or your `free_irq()` doesn't get called (or doesn't finish successfully). Perhaps some debugging is needed to figure out the root cause. Can you apply patch from [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/arm-kernel/msg528469.html) and paste the corresponding output from kernel log? Btw, I guess it would be better to create a new question on SO, as it seems to be out of scope here.

Comment: thanks for the link to the patch. I definitely will do debugging and probably will post a new question/answer myself. I just thought that this could have been some known issue that I'm unaware of or something that I could have been doing wrong. Thanks.