# I've added a MAX7320 i2c output chip. How can I get the kernel to load the driver for it?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-tree, max732x.c

I've added a MAX7320 i2c expander chip to i2c bus 0 on my ARM Linux board.

The chip works correctly from userspace with commands such as `/usr/sbin/i2cset -y 0 0x5d 0x02` and `/usr/sbin/i2cget -y 0 0x5d`.

There is a `drivers/gpio/gpio-max732x.c` file in the kernel source, which is compiled into the kernel that I'm running.  (I've built it from source.)

How do I tell the kernel that it should instantiate the gpio-max732x driver on "i2c bus 0, chip id 0x5d"?

Do I need to modify the device tree `.dts` file and put a new `.dtb` file in `/boot/dtbs/`?

What would the clause for instantiating a `gpio-max732x` module look like?

P.S. I've seen https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/1/13/305 but I can't figure out how to get the patch files.

Comment: Take alook [At this Doc](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt) or [This Doc](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-pca953x.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Device Tree

There must be appropriate Device Tree definition for your chip, in order for driver to instantiate. There are 2 ways to do so:

1. Modify `.dts` Device Tree file for your board (look in `arch/arm/boot/dts/)`, then recompile it and re-flash it to your device.

   This way is preferred in case when you have access you kernel sources for your board and you are able to re-flash `.dtb` file to your  device.
2. Create [Device Tree Overlay](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/overlay-notes.txt) file, compile it and [load](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md#part3.5) it on your device.

   This way is preferred when you don't have access to kernel sources for your board, or you are unable to flash new device tree blob to your device.

Your device definition in Device Tree should look like (according to [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt)):

```
&i2c0 {
    expander: max7320@5d {
        compatible = "maxim,max7320";
        reg = <0x5d>;
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
    };
};
```

### Kernel configuration

As your expander chip (MAX7320) has no input GPIOs, you don't need IRQ support for MAX732x. So you can disable `CONFIG_GPIO_MAX732X_IRQ` in your kernel configuration.

### Matching device with driver

Once you have your Device Tree loaded (with definition for MAX7320), MAX732x driver will be matched with device definition, and instantiated. Below is explained how matching happens.

In Device Tree file you have `compatible` property:

```
compatible = "maxim,max7320";
```

In MAX732x driver you can see this table:

```c
static const struct of_device_id max732x_of_table[] = {
    ...
    { .compatible = "maxim,max7320" },
    ...
```

When driver is being loaded, and when Device Tree blob is being loaded, kernel tries to find the match for each driver and Device Tree definition. Just by comparing strings above. If strings are matched -- kernel instantiates driver, passing corresponding device parameters to it. Look at [i2c_device_match()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c?v=4.5#L503) function for details.

### Obtaining patches

The best way is to use kernel sources that already have Device Tree support of MAX732x (v4.0+). But if it's not the case, then...

You can cherry-pick patches from upstream kernel to your kernel:

```
$ git remote add upstream git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
$ git fetch --all
$ git cherry-pick 43c4bcf9425e
$ git cherry-pick 479f8a5744d8
$ git cherry-pick 09afa276d52e
$ git cherry-pick 996bd13f28e6
```

And if you still want to apply patches manually (worst option, actually), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933950/3866447) you can find direct links to patches. Click **(patch)** link to get a raw patch.

Also check later patches for `gpio-max732x.c` [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?qt=grep&q=max732).

### Hardware concerns

To be sure that your chip has `0x5d` I2C address, check that configuration pins are tied to next lines (as per [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7320.pdf)):

```
Pin    Line
-----------
AD2     V+
AD0     V+
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, I didn't expect to be answered by the author of the patch :)  I didn't even know about `Documentation/devicetree/bindings` or Device Tree Overlays.

Comment: Why does http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt?v=4.0 exist in 4.0 onwards if the support was not introduced until 4.2?  (Not an academic question - I only have 4.1.15 for this board.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, my patches were merged in v4.0. You can check it easily using next command: `git tag --contains 43c4bcf9425e | head`. I just used some other (later) patch to determine corresponding tag.